# eslint configured the same for 2 folders, but linting differently

Tags: node.js, express, npm, vue.js, eslint

Before I start, I just want to mention I'm studying and learning to use a proper workflow with git, vue, express, npm, cli and webpack.  I'm very new to these concepts but have been enjoying learning and troubleshooting this as I go along.  I've been watching a popular video tutorial (I'll link if it is ok) on using VueJS with Express.  In the past I've been just a standard html/php, javascript/jquery, css dev with no cli tools.  I decided to dive head first after seeing how amazing these tools are and having that 'AHA' moment while using them.

I finished the first part of the tutorial which was setting up node, npm, etc...  I created a git repository (here https://github.com/drpcken/tab_tracker), made my first commit (wow that was fun) and started going through the tutorial after getting all my dependencies configured and using nodemon and eslint in the terminal to see issues.

Now my project has it's main project folder, and then a `client` and `server` subfolder that separates my frontend (vue) and backend (express).  The tutorial had me setup eslint using the `standard` style guide.  I quickly realized I didn't want this since `standard` doesn't require semicolons at the end of each line (I'm old fashioned and preferred them).  I then realized that the linting I wanted was `airbnb`.  So last night, while working in my `server` folder I ran the command to init my eslint:  `node ./node_modules/eslint/bin/eslint.js --init` and changed the style guide to `airbnb`.  It worked beautifully, and I happily committed my changed to my repository this morning.

When I woke up and started studying again this morning, it dawned on me that my `client` folder also needed to have the eslint initialized and switched to `airbnb` style guide.  So I did so, the same way I initlaized eslint on my server folder.   However, it seems that it didn't take.  If I add a semicolon to the end of one of my js files in the client folder, my compiler/terminal complains:

```
 ✘  http://eslint.org/docs/rules/semi  Extra semicolon
  src/router/index.js:2:32
  import Router from 'vue-router';
```

I have no clue why this would happen.  I configured eslint to use `airbnb` the same way as my `server` folder.  Here is a link to my repo:  https://github.com/drpcken/tab_tracker

In short: switching from `standard` style guide to `airbnb` lints differently in one folder than the other.  `server` folder lints properly with `airbnb` (requiring semicolon) but my `client` folder, using the same `airbnb` linting does not (gives an error when I add semicolons).

Comment: Try removing `eslint-standard` from your `package.json` it might me something related to your editor picking it up. I know some standard plugins for editors look for the existence of standard on the package.json.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your server side code uses `require` whereas your client side code does it using `import`. So yeah, you cannot actually compare the validity of the same amongst both of them.

If you have the look at the documentation [here](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/semi) ( which you may trace from the link above the error snippet you shared ), you may realize this : It is not the airbnb style guide but the eslint default rule for ASI ( aka automatic semicolon insertion) . You may wish to remove the influence of the same from your code.

Addendum : As [Fabio Antunes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1449157/fabio-antunes) just commented, you may wish to remove the eslint-standard from your package.json. Let us know if that helps.